# Custom Github Login with Meteor is not working

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I've being following step by step the Custom Login tutorial from Eventedmind showing in this link:

https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login

So I've created a new App on Github and code it but while running Meteor I still have errors and nothing shows up. I know I've got errors from the server side, but I have no idea what is it, maybe the code is bad written or maybe the way I am calling the login is not the proper anymore. Here is what I've done (I guess is the same as in the tutorial)

client/index.html

```
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> header}}
</body>

<template name="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="brand" href="#">NewApp</a>
            <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
            <div class="nav pull_right">
                {{> user_info}}
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="user_info">
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> user_loggedin}}
    {{else}}
        {{> user_loggedout}}
    {{/if}}
  </ul>  
</template>


<template name="user_loggedin">
    {{#if loggingIn}}
        <li><a href="">Loggin in...</a></li>
    {{else}}
        <li>
            <img src="{{currentUser.profile.avatar_url}}" class="img-rounded" style="height: 32px; margin-top: 4px;">
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{currentUser.profile.login}}
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="">Accounts Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a id="logout">logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
</template>


<template name="user_loggedout">
  <li><a id="login">Login with Github</a></li>
</template>
```

client/index.js

```
Template.user_loggedout.events({
  'click #login': function (e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.loginWithGithub({
      requestPermissions: ['user', 'public_repo']
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        // error handling
      } else {
        // show alert
      }
    });
  }
});

Template.user_loggedin.events({
  'click #logout': function (e, tmpl) {
    Meteor.logout(function (e, tmpl) {
      if (err) {
        // show err message
      } else{
        // show alert that says logged out
      }
    });
  }
});
```

server/config.js

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
    service: "github"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    service: "github",
    clientId: "NUMBER",
    secret: "SECRET_NUMBER"
});
```

server/accounts.js

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    var accessToken = user.services.github.accessToken,
        result,
        profile;
    result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
        params: {
            access_token: accessToken
        }
    });
    if (result.error)
        throw result.error;

    profile = _.pick(result.data,
        "login",
        "name",
        "avatar_url",
        "url",
        "company",
        "blog",
        "location",
        "email",
        "bio",
        "html_url");

    user.profile = profile;

    return user;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest github API requires a HTTP User-Agent header in every request. Just include it as below.

```
result = Meteor.http.get("https://api.github.com/user", {
  headers: {"User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"},
  params: {
    access_token: accessToken
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you arent seeing anything rendering on the page at all...

in your client/index.js try adding

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.Router.add({
      '/': 'index'  
    });
}
```

Im new to meteor, but I think when you put something in the /client/ directory structure you have to route to it.

I might be wrong, but you could also just try putting everything in the root folder and wrapping client side stuff with

```
if(Meteor.isClient)
```

and server stuff with

```
if(Meteor.isServer)
```

I cant really tell if you are saying nothing on the page is rendering at all or only after you login.

Comment: Meteor will load the index.js automatically in "client mode". The solution from @pallavi-anderson works like a charm